# BehaviorSubject.First() obsolete, what is the alternative?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

So I have a `BehaviorSubject<string>` which I wish to use for a property. I have been using the blocking `First()` method to get the current value that the `BehaviorSubject` holds in a property getter.

The `First()` operation is now obsolete, so what is the new way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you share the text of the warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `BehaviorSubject<T>` you are guaranteed* to have a `First` value always available.

However, `IObservable<T>` query operators can't work under that assumption in general, so the `Obsolete` attribute was added to drive people towards asynchronous methods like `FirstAsync` - helping them to "fall into the pit of success".

Because of the special case of `BehaviorSubject<T>` always having a value set, it has a thread safe `Value` property. So, assuming that you have something like this:

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Some value");
```

Then you can do this:

```
var current = subject.Value;
```

**Attempting to acess the value of a `BehaviorSubject<T>` instance after its `Dispose` method has been called, whether by the `Value` property or a query operator like `FirstAsync`, will cause an `ObjectDisposedException` to be thrown.*

Answer (score 9):

James's answer is great, but I thought it worth mentioning the general alternatives to `First` that works for any IObservable.  But definitely use the `Value` property if you know it is a BehaviorSubject.

```
// synchronously wait for the value
var value = someObservable.FirstAsync().Wait();

// async await
var value = await someObservable.FirstAsync();
```

Comment: This is actually what I am after as I expose an `IObservable`, however, technically, the other response answers is more applicable to the question so I have upvoted this and marked the other response as correct.

Comment: BehaviorSubject is a bit annoying because you can't expose the Value without exposing the full BehaviorSubject.  It'd be nice if there was a IBehaviorObservable which extended IObservable with a .Value property.